# ConcurrentHashMap JDK 8 when to use computeIfPresent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

The new version of Concurrent Hash Map of jdk 8 has two new Methods.

**computeIfAbsent**

**computeIfPresent**

**putIfAbsent**  - Old method

I understand the use cases of **putIfAbsent** and **computeIfAbsent**.
But i am not sure of the scenarios when i will use **computeIfPresent**.
Also why do i need putIfAbsent if i have computeIfPresent now.
*putIfAbsent do create atleast one extra instance of the value.*

Is the reason is only to have backward compatability?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer: Methods will always be kept for backward compatibility, even if there are new, more "powerful" methods introduced.

Concerning the use case for `computeIfPresent`: It may be hard to find an example that is small enough to not look contrived and still be convincing. In general, the intention of this method is to *update* an existing value in any form.

One example could be a (constrained) **word count**: For a given set of words, one stores an initial count of `0` in the map. Then, a sequence of words is processed: Whenever one finds a word from the initial set, its count is increased by 1:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ComputeIfPresentExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        String s = 
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur iam nonumy sadipscing " + 
            "elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut erat sed " + 
            "labore et dolore magna dolor sit amet aliquyam erat sed diam";

        wordCounts.put("sed", 0);
        wordCounts.put("erat", 0);

        for (String t : s.split(" "))
        {
            wordCounts.computeIfPresent(t, (k,v) -> v+1);
        }
        System.out.println(wordCounts);
    }
}
```

(Of course, things like this could be solved differently, but this is a rather frequent task in one or the other form, and the new method allows a rather concise and elegant solution)

Comment: Another perk of `computeIfPresent`: the value parameter for the `BiFunction` is assured to be non null.

Answer (score 17):

A common use case are [maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), like

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> strings = new HashMap<>();
```

[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) are very handy operations for adding and removing elements to/from the collection. Not least because unlike `put()`, the `compute*()` methods return the current value (whether it was just created or not). Here's an example that groups strings by their first char. Note that both the keys and the collections are created when necessary and cleaned it up when the collection becomes empty:

```
void addString(String a) {
    String index = a.substring(0, 1);
    strings.computeIfAbsent(index, ign -> new HashSet<>()).add(a);
}

void removeString(String a) {
    String index = a.substring(0, 1);
    strings.computeIfPresent(index, (k, c) -> {
        c.remove(a);
        return c.isEmpty() ? null : c;
    });
}
```

Example:

```
                         // {}
addString("a1");         // {a=[a1]}      <-- collection dynamically created
addString("a2");         // {a=[a1, a2]}
removeString("a1");      // {a=[a2]}
removeString("a2");      // {}            <-- both key and collection removed
```

This is extremely powerful in multithreading environments as [`ConcurrentMaps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) perform these operations atomically.

The remove operation can be a one-liner:

```
void removeString(String a) {
    String index = a.substring(0, 1);
    strings.computeIfPresent(index, (i, c) -> c.remove(a) && c.isEmpty() ? null : c);
}
```

So once again in short:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent(key, i -> ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()).add(value);
map.computeIfPresent(key, (i, s) -> s.remove(value) && s.isEmpty() ? null : s);
```

Comment: This is the real use-case for `computeIfPresent`.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK hardly ever breaks backwards compatibility. Because then you can not easily port or run software from an older version with the latest version.

You can run software compiled with an older version of the library with any version (meaning users that have the JRE installed) that still has those functions.

Comment: @thriller ohh i know it has to be backward compatability. my question is it the only  reason? and also usecase of computeIfPresent.